# Checking for values in XSLT and condition

Tags: xslt

Rephrasing my question properly:

I have XSLT where I need to check for node values for specific data. 
E.g. (pseudocode):

```
If only H occurs then set target element value as 'H'
Else if
    Only B or N then set target element value as 'BN'
```

If Source XML:

```
<n1>N</n1>
<n1>B</n1>
<n1>N</n1>
```

Target node:
    BN

If Source XML:

```
<n1>H</n1>
<n1>H</n1>
<n1>H</n1>
```

Target node:
    H

There is no attribute. I have to only set text on meeting the condition in the target node.

Can I use something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="elements">
<xsl:for-each select="/test/elem">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:if test="position() < last()">
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Would the above give me concat of all element values and then I can do a check to see the if that contains x then I can do a set text?

Comment: There is *no* question. Also, the text contradicts the actual XML fragment -- there is no `H` anhywhere... ?!? Please, edir your question and provide a complete XML document. Also explain what result you want to be produced -- the word "assign" is especially confusing -- maybe you meant "output"?

Comment: When you say "assign" what do you mean? You want it to be output as text? You want it to be the text of some element or attribute? You want it to be in a variable? Please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/root[not(n1 != 'H')]">
                <xsl:value-of select="'H'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/root[not(n1[. != 'B' and . != 'N'])]">
                <xsl:value-of select="'BN'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'Something else'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>$value = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### is given this input

```
<root>
    <n1>H</n1>
    <n1>H</n1>
    <n1>H</n1>
</root>
```

#### it produces the desired output

```
$value = H
```

Similarly with

```
<root>
    <n1>N</n1>
    <n1>B</n1>
    <n1>N</n1>
</root>
```

or with

```
<root>
    <n1>N</n1>
    <n1>N</n1>
    <n1>N</n1>
</root>
```

we get

```
$value = BN
```

And with

```
<root>
    <n1>N</n1>
    <n1>B</n1>
    <n1>x</n1>
</root>
```

or with

```
<root>
    <n1>N</n1>
    <n1>B</n1>
    <n1>H</n1>
</root>
```

we get

```
$value = Something else
```

The string `H`, `BN` or `Something else` is the value of a variable. Instead of just outputting the value of that variable you can of course set it as the contents of a new element you create.